# problem with Casting in C ( (int*) (char*))

Tags: c

so here is the code, till the 4th print out I easily followed it, but at the 5th printout, I don't understand

why its `"5: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 128144, a[2] = 256, a[3] = 302 "`?

I got the point of `a[1]` but I'm still thinking about how `a[2]` come 256?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(void)
{
    int a[4];
    int *b = malloc(16);
    int *c;
    int i;

    printf("1: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);

    c = a;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    a[i] = 100 + i;
    c[0] = 200;
    printf("2: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
       a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c[1] = 300;
    *(c + 2) = 301;
    3[c] = 302;
    printf("3: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
       a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c = c + 1;
    *c = 400;
    printf("4: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
       a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);
    *c = 500;
    printf("5: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
       a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    b = (int *) a + 1;
    c = (int *) ((char *) a + 1);
    printf("6: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);
    
    
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Can you show us the output for 4

Comment: This might be helpful to get an idea of your architecture and memory layout, but casting a `char*` back to `int*` is undefined behavior, and gcc is known for punishing undefined behavior with vengeance.

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);
```

May be putting you into undefined behavior (technically), but it can be reliably explained on an Intel processor.

Your 4th print statement shows this:

```
4: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 400, a[2] = 301, a[3] = 302
```

Assuming little Endian for Intel chips and `sizeof(int)==4`for int (most likely), your memory layout at the addresses referenced by `a` and `c` are as follows.  `c` points to `&a[1]` at this point.

```
C8 00 00 00 90 01 00 00 2D 01 00 00 2E 01 00 00 XX XX XX
[   A[0]  ] [   A[1]  ] [   A[2]  ] [  A[3]   ]
            [   C[0]  ] [   C[1]  ] [  C[2]   ]
```

So when you say `c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);`, you've shifted your view of the memory array above by 1 byte.  Hence `c` is now pointing at the second byte within `A[1]`, or as a flattened array:

```
C8 00 00 00 90 01 00 00 2D 01 00 00 2E 01 00 00 XX XX XX
[   A[0]  ] [   A[1]  ] [   A[2]  ] [  A[3]   ]
               [   C[0]  ] [   C[1]  ] [  C[2]   ]
```

Then this statement happens.

```
*c = 500;
```

That going to convert the byte values at `C[0]` which is currently `01 00 00 2D` to be `500` which in little endian hex is `F4 01 00 00`.  That adjusts memory values as follows:

```
               | CHANGED |
C8 00 00 00 90 F4 01 00 00 01 00 00 2E 01 00 00 XX
[   A[0]  ] [   A[1]  ] [   A[2]  ] [  A[3]   ]
               [   C[0]  ] [   C[1]  ] [  C[2]   ]
```

As a result, the `2D` value that was occupying the first byte of A[2] is now `00`.

So A[2] contains `00 01 00 00` which in little endian converts to `0x00000100`, which is `256`.

There's some rule breaking going on with the above code, but code doing pointer math like above isn't uncommon in the `C` world and is reliably implemented by compilers.  Note, there are certain architectures, like Sparc, where writing to an integer pointer that is not word aligned on a 4-byte boundary will generate an exception ([SIGBUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) signal leading to program crash). Somewhere between the OS and the CPU architecture for Intel/Windows, this is handled for you (albeit slower).

Comment: Thank you for ur justification, it became easier now :)

Comment: If you found the answer useful, don't forget to upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: I hope I can do this, but the site doesn't allow me to upvote anyone as I'm a new student :(

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is in binary (little-endian). After `Step: 4` your array in memory is:

```
a[0] : 11001000-00000000-00000000-00000000
a[1] : 10010000-00000001-00000000-00000000
a[2] : 00101101-00000001-00000000-00000000
a[3] : 00101110-00000001-00000000-00000000
```

At this point `c` points to `a[1]`. The expression:

```
c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);
```

Adds one BYTE (`sizeof(char) == 1`), so when you assign `*c = 500;` you are assigning that to the 2nd byte of `a[1]`, and since arrays are contiguous in memory, the last byte of `500` overwrites the first byte in `a[2]`.

A visual descriptions of what is taking place would be:

```
a[1] : 10010000-00000001-00000000-00000000
                ^
   c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);
   
a[1] : 10010000-00000001-00000000-00000000
                +   
500  :          11110100-00000001-00000000-00000000
                                           ^
                                   overwrites LSB of a[2]
```

This leaves the state of your array after the assignment as:

```
a[0] : 11001000-00000000-00000000-00000000
a[1] : 10010000-11110100-00000001-00000000
a[2] : 00000000-00000001-00000000-00000000
a[3] : 00101110-00000001-00000000-00000000
```

Where the values of `a[1]` and `a[2]` are:

```
a[1] : 11111010010010000  (128,144)
a[2] : 100000000              (256)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for ur help, I really appreciate your kind assistance. I got it!

Comment: Glad to help. It was an interesting question. Since this is a 1D array, there isn't a strict aliasing violation. [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) (it's not the finest example of clarity, but the last bullet point explicitly allowing access through `char` saves you)